# ELK - micro service and network latency monitoring

Tags: network-monitoring

Does ELK stack provide  micro service and network latency monitoring in kibana?

[Zipkin](https://zipkin.io/) provides details about service request and service response duration.

In behind ELS stack should trace span events:

cs - Client Sent

sr - Server Received

ss - Server Sent

cr - Client Received

Comment: How can we tell ? you don't give a clue on how you'd push data on Elasticsearch and what data they are.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ELK stack does not provide monitoring. It only provides reporting unless you configure additional add-ons such as [ElastAlert](http://elastalert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/elastalert.html).

ELK also only reports (or alerts if configured) on the data that you feed into it. So to turn the question around:

> Do you have your network devices configured to send micro service and network latency logging information to your ELK stack?

If yes, then the answer will be yes. If no, then the answer will be no.

ELK is nothing more than a system for processing and reporting metadata and generating structured data from plaintext logs, so it will do whatever you configure it to do.

Comment: Elasticsearch 6 brings an APM agent and some dashboard for classes call time, but I haven't tried it for now

Comment: @Tensibai Yes APM is the solution. However it is beta.  Also, Davide developed POC for spring boot as well. https://github.com/davidecavestro/elastic-apm-java-agent-poc